# Alternate to button

Tags: gui-design, buttons

I have a long text "view/hide basic specifications" and I don't want to provide a button as that doesn't look good at the required location how can I give user that function without a button so that it looks good and fulfills the purpose.

Comment: Maybe a switch would work ? Change text to View base specs?

Comment: You can add a little eye icon with the text next to it, underlined and in blue.

Comment: There's no correct answer to this. It's more of a discussion topic or something you'd get the team around a whiteboard to brainstorm the best idea. The measurable criteria for an answer here is just 'it looks good / bad' which doesn't really fit with how this site works as it's entirely subjective. And it also is written with the result that it encourages icon suggestions (which is off-topic for this site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If long text buttons is not an option for you then your can opt for other options. 
Instead of button you can go with plain hyper link or an alternative to text can be an Icon image, but at times icons does not looks self explanatory, to tackle that problem you can add a tool-tip to the icon.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.Yes I implemented it  as a hyperlink any better solution is also welcomed.

Comment: How about using icons?